# Results summary reporting z instead of t value for multiple OLS regression using statsmodelforumla?

Tags: pandas, statistics, data-science, linear-regression, statsmodels

I want to do report the results summary with t value but it keeps coming back with the z value in the summary even though I tried to correct it with the "use_T=True".

```
model=smf.ols("gr_gdp_pc ~ ln_gdp + gr_cap_pc + gr_rent_pc + lag_index_all_z", data=df)

result = model.fit(cov_type='HAC', cov_kwds={'maxlags':1}, use_T=True)

print(result.summary())
```

So my results table looks like this:
[image]

I'm open to other ways of doing the regression. I just need robust standard errors (HAC makes most sense for this data) and t-values make more sense than z. Please help!!!

Comment: This should have raised an exception. The keyword is misspelled, it's `use_t=True` (lower case t)

Comment: AFAICS, `fit` in linear regression uses kwargs to set attributes for the results instance. I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8758